# What's the history behind the Functor type class?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

I'm trying to gain a really deep understanding of the `Monad` hierarchy of classes.  Part of that is, of course, seeing lots of examples, but I'm particularly interested in the history of how these classes were first discovered and their motivations.

I understand that `Monad`s came about initially as a solution to the IO problem in Haskell, and am familiar with papers by Moggi and Wadler in 1989-92 that introduced them.

I've also seen where `Applicatives` were introducted in Conor McBride and Ross Paterson's "Applicative Programming with Effects."

By my question is what popularized `Functor`s, and when did they come about?  I assume it must be after `Monad` since `Functor` is not a superclass, but haven't people been using generalized map functions since the early days of LISP?

Comment: The Functor class was first  (before 1.3 was released) a superclass of Monad, but this was (sadly) retracted because people felt it was an unnecessary superclass.

Comment: "[H]aven't people been using generalized map functions since the early days of LISP?" Well, there is one difference, in that most of the time these "generalized map functions" are collection- or even sequence-based. Even today you see this in, e.g., Clojure, where [the `map` function takes collections and returns lazy sequences](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/map). In contrast, the `Functor` class is based on equational laws, and makes no assumption about the implementation, leading to non-collection implementations like `IO` and FRP `Behavior` types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Functor` was in the 1.3 version of the Haskell report which is what standardized both monadic IO and higher kinded type classes.  So, the `Functor` typeclass is as old as the monad typeclass.  And, what is more, `Functor` is the first motivating example in Jones' paper introducting "constructor classes!"  You might say the Jones paper popularized the idea, but as you point out people have wanted generalized maps for a long time indead.

Comment: Indeed. Jones implemented constructor classes in Gofer some time before they were adopted in Haskell. Hugs is short for Haskell Users' Gofer System, introduced to allow Haskell folk access to some more advanced type system stuff, in the days before ghc was cutting edge.

Comment: Excellent!  This looks like an awesome paper, and the first section is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The paper is at http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150GIT/archive/mark-jones/fpca93.pdf